# Websphere 8.5.5.12 - Spring Boot not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere, was

My spring boot applications working great on tomcat. But I need to deploy this in IBM **Websphere 8.5.5.12** and there my troubles began.

I had referred to [article](https://medium.com/@james.tran/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-2-x-apps-on-websphere-8-5-5-d0b2e257f606) and added the dependency '*spring-boot-starter-validation*' to avoid the error:

> Error activating Bean Validation integration Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager

But if I keep it, I receive another error

> Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
>   incompatible with javax.el.ExpressionFactory

Please note that on WAS, I have already ensured local class loading to load first over parent.
>

> In the administrative console, click Applications > >Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > >application_name > Manage modules > webmodule_name.
>   Select Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent >last) from the drop down list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved!!!

After multiple attempts, I finally used and this fixed my issue:

> compile(group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '3.0.0')

instead of below mentioned in [article](https://medium.com/@james.tran/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-2-x-apps-on-websphere-8-5-5-d0b2e257f606)

> compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:
>   'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE')

End days for Websphere, I felt with the frustration of this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on 8.5.5.16 . If I try it I am getting the same catch-22 situation.

if I have it there, I get ClassCastException , if I remove it I get NoClassDefFoundError